# Why are the functions open() and send() invoked after the anonymous function() in the code below.?t

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

From what I understand, the request for the file on server should be made first and sent to it. Once the server gets ready to process the request, the anonymous function should be executed. I am unable to understand the flow of execution.
I am also confused when to use `true` or `false` in the argument of the function `open()`.

Comment: `onreadystatechange` is not called before `open` and `send` - whatever gives you the idea it is? Also, for your second question - its all covered in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open)

Answer (score 1):

`onreadystatechange` is an event handler. The function gets called when the event happens. This is much like:

```
document.body.onclick = function () { ... };
```

The assignment just assigns the function to the property, it doesn't call it immediately. That would need `()` on the end (or the use of `apply` or something similar).

> I am also confused when to use true or false in the argument of the function open().

Setting it to `false` is deprecated, so don't do that ever. `true` is the default, so you can omit it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the `xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true)`
The open method takes 3 paramaters

1. request type: generally a *GET* or a *POST*
2. URL : the url to be called
3. async: true (asynchronous) or false

Setting to false has been deprecated so you can leave out the 3rd param as it's true by default

`xhttp.send()` to initiate the request

`xhttp.onreadystatechange` is an event handler with is not fired immediately but fires when the state changed.

Answer (score -1):

Just to clear up the matter:

The `function ()` ,is called `onreadystatechange` when the State change of the request. *(btw.: `function()` is an anonymous function that is **asigned** to the `onreadystatechange` eventListener)*

The function that is assigned to the `onreadystatechange` eventListener is called **everytime** when the state of the XMLHttpRequest object changes.

**So you should be aware that this function is called multiple times**
you can check this with an `if` statement, like so

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  // when using on a local - file
  if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
    // ...do something
  }
}
```

to prevent unwanted multiple executions.
*(checking for other `readyState` can be use for loadingscreens and more)*

The `true` or `false` parameter passed to the `open` function, says if the call should be async or not. Meaning if it should wait until, the server returns the response. If the script wait's the whole page will freeze until the call is finished.

Here is a list from the [MDN Documentation open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) of the possible parameter:

```
void open(
   DOMString method,           // GET, POST, ...
   DOMString url,              // URL
   optional boolean async,     // if true script continuse executing
   optional DOMString user,    // Username if needed 
   optional DOMString password // password if needed
);
```

**I recommend to read the Documentation, on function, objects and so on if you are insecure.**

Here some good Link to this specific topic (XMLHttpRequest):
[MDN XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

**Here a small visualisation of the "flow"**

```
[enter loadDoc()] --call--> xhttp.open(..., true) --call-->  xhttp.send(...) --> [exit loadDoc()]

[onEvent "readystatechange" ] --> xhttp.onreadystatechange(...)
```

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I wasn't finished with my answer, I was answering incremental, as 'advised' some years on a SO - Article, on how to answer. My english is not so fluent so I need some time to write.